# How to convert Tailwind CSS into a class and put it in a CSS file?

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I started using Tailwind to style my app. It is very useful but I would like to put all the css in one file. I don't want to see it with HTML code.

I tried converting the following div:

```
<div className="relative w-9 h-5 bg-gray-200 peer-focus:outline-none peer-focus:ring-4 peer-focus:ring-blue-300 dark:peer-focus:ring-blue-800 rounded-full peer dark:bg-gray-700 peer-checked:after:translate-x-full rtl:peer-checked:after:-translate-x-full peer-checked:after:border-white after:content-[''] after:absolute after:top-[2px] after:start-[2px] after:bg-white after:border-gray-300 after:border after:rounded-full after:h-4 after:w-4 after:transition-all dark:border-gray-600 peer-checked:bg-blue-600"></div>
```

with the following command (that i put in my app.css file):

```
.checkbox-style {
  @apply relative w-9 h-5 bg-gray-200 peer-focus:outline-none peer-focus:ring-4 peer-focus:ring-blue-300 dark:peer-focus:ring-blue-800 rounded-full peer dark:bg-gray-700 peer-checked:after:translate-x-full rtl:peer-checked:after:-translate-x-full peer-checked:after:border-white after:content-[''] after:absolute after:top-[2px] after:start-[2px] after:bg-white after:border-gray-300 after:border after:rounded-full after:h-4 after:w-4 after:transition-all dark:border-gray-600 peer-checked:bg-blue-600;
}
```

But it doesn't work. I get error `unknown rule at apply`. Would you know how to correct it?

I'm using tailwind css 3.4.1 and react 18.2.0.

Comment: It would be great if we can move tailwind back to CSS though!

Answer (score 0):

Applying complex styles with Tailwind CSS `@apply` directive can be trickier than simply copying and pasting the utility classes from the element to the CSS file. The `@apply` directive can’t be used with styles that insert:

- content, like `::before` and `::after` selectors
- pseudo-classes such as `:checked`
- styles that have complex variants.

So you could refactor your code like this:

> HTML

```
<div className="checkbox-style"></div>
```

> CSS

```
.checkbox-style {
  @apply relative w-9 h-5 bg-gray-200 rounded-full dark:bg-gray-700;
}

.checkbox-style:after {
  @apply absolute top-2 start-2 bg-white border-gray-300 border rounded-full h-4 w-4 transition-all;
}

.checkbox-style:focus-within {
  @apply outline-none ring-4 ring-blue-300 dark:ring-blue-800;
}

.checkbox-style:checked {
  background-color: #3182ce; /* blue-600 */
  transform: translateX(100%);
}

.checkbox-style:checked:after {
  border-color: white;
}
```

Unfortunately, the `@apply` directive with the `peer` variant in Tailwind might not work as expected in some cases due to its complexity. However, you can use:

> JavaScript or React to handle the state of the checkbox and apply
> styles based on its state

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";

function App() {
  const [isChecked, setChecked] = useState(false);
  
  const toggleChecked = () => {
    setChecked(!isChecked);
  };

  return (
    <div 
      className={`checkbox-style ${isChecked ? "checked" : ""}`}
      onClick={toggleChecked}
    ></div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

> Mantain them inline, like you are doing.

---

[Tailwind CSS Just-In-Time (JIT)](https://v2.tailwindcss.com/docs/just-in-time-mode) is an handle on-the-fly arbitrary styles that arise from using JavaScript, thus enabling better handling of pseudo-classes.

With the `peer` variants, you specify a state at an element's level, but you want to apply a style to a `"peer"` element. However, even with `JIT`, the `peer` and `peer-checked` variants still work best with inline utility styles - not via your CSS files where you are using `@apply` directive.